# Formulário de email não funciona apenas em smartphones!

Tags: php, html5, css3, phpmailer, slimframework

Olá, pessoal! Tudo certo?
Esse é minha primeira postagem aqui. Estou com um problema meio bobo, mas há três, quatro dias! 
Comecei a desenvolver há pouco tempo e esse é meu primeiro projeto comercial. Ele está praticamente pronto, mas o meu formulário de email não está funcionando quando a resolução é de 360px (para smartphones). O engraçado é que funciona para desktops, funciona em notebooks, em tablets, mas não para celular. Outra informação importante é que ele não está local, já está em servidor.

Para a coleta e envio das informações, eu estou usando PHPMailer. Vou passar os códigos-fonte para, por gentileza, darem uma olhada!

Além do PHPMailer, também estou usando o slim Framework v2 e bootstrap 3.

**FORMULÁRIO DE CONTATO - DESKTOPS**

```
 <div class="contato-Coluna1 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h4>ENTRE EM CONTATO</h4>
        <hr>

        <form action="mail" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campoNome" placeholder="Nome: ">                 
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">                  
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campoCidade" placeholder="Cidade: ">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">                  
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="campoEmail" placeholder="Email: ">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">                  
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="campoTelefone" placeholder="Telefone: ">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="comment">Deixe sua mensagem:</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="campoMensagem"></textarea>
              </div>                  

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEnviarForm">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**CÓDIGO-FONTE VERSÃO MOBILE**

```
    <div class="mobileContato visible-xs visible-sm">
    <h4 class="text-center">ENTRE EM CONTATO</h4>
        <hr>

        <form action="mail" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campoNome" placeholder="Nome: ">                 
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">                  
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campoCidade" placeholder="Cidade: ">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">                  
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="campoEmail" placeholder="Email: ">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">                  
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="campoTelefone" placeholder="Telefone: ">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="comment">Deixe sua mensagem:</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="campoMensagem"></textarea>
              </div>                  

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEnviarForm">Enviar</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

**CONFIGURAÇÃO DO PHPMAILER**
(Eu retirei as informações como emails e senhas aqui do código, mas nessa parte, está tudo certinho. Tanto que, como eu disse, para desktop ele envia).

```
$app->post(
'/mail',
function () {

    $nome = $_POST['campoNome'];
    $cidade = $_POST['campoCidade'];
    $email = $_POST['campoEmail'];
    $tel = $_POST['campoTelefone'];
    $msg = $_POST['campoMensagem'];

    $mensagem = "<strong>Nome: </strong>" . $nome . "<br>";
    $mensagem .= "<strong>Cidade: </strong>" . $cidade . "<br>";
    $mensagem .= "<strong>Email: </strong>" . $email . "<br>";
    $mensagem .= "<strong>Telefone: </strong>" . $tel . "<br><br>";
    $mensagem .= "<strong>Mensagem: </strong>" . "<br>" . $msg;

    require_once("class/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->IsSMTP();

    try {
         $mail->Host = '' ; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (Autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
         $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
         $mail->Port       = 587; //  Usar 587 porta SMTP
         $mail->Username = ''; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
         $mail->Password = ''; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

         //Define o remetente
         // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=    
         $mail->SetFrom('', ''); //Seu e-mail
         $mail->AddReplyTo('', ''); //Seu e-mail
         $mail->Subject = '' . $nome;//Assunto do e-mail

        //Define os destinatário(s)
         //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
         $mail->AddAddress('', '');

         //Define o corpo do email
         $mail->MsgHTML('corpo do email'); 

         $mail->Body = $mensagem;

         $mail->Send();


         //caso apresente algum erro é apresentado abaixo com essa exceção.
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            echo $e->errorMessage(); //Mensagem de erro costumizada do PHPMailer
          }
});
```

Se puderem, então, me ajudar nisso, ficarei muito grato pois só está faltando isso para finalizar o projeto.

Valeu pessoal!

Comment: Poste o trecho que aciona o envio do email...

Comment: Desculpe @ÐvÐ! Eu só pude ver agora a sua mensagem! 
Então, na verdade para a versão para desktop existe um link de navegação "Contato.php" onde a pessoa entra e lá, além do mapinha do Google Maps, tem um formulário de contato. Esse está funcionando normalmente. Eu testei e redirecionei as mensagens para o meu email particular e estão chegando normalmente. 

Para a versão "mobile", eu deixei o formulário de contato já no "index" com a intenção de ser algo mais objetivo. E é esse que não vai de jeito nenhum. Quando você clica em enviar, é como se desse um refresh na página, mas não envia.

Comment: @AndréBaill obrigado pela resposta, só que, na verdade, seria esse trecho do phpmailer que envia, ou estou errado?
Desculpe minha inexperiência!

Comment: Boa noite! Tudo jóia?
Exato, @ÐvÐ, é EXATAMENTE isso. 
Eu fiz o seguinte (vou enumerar para não confundir):
1. A ideia é ter uma confirmação tanto para envio de desktops quanto para mobile. 
2. A versão desktop funciona. Se você enviar, ele dá um refresh e na div que está o formulário, ele é substituído por uma frase de envio com sucesso. 
3. No caso do mobile, eu tinha feito a mesma coisa, mas não acontece isso. Quando você clica em "enviar", ele dá o refresh, mas é como se você tivesse apertado o F5. Não aparece a frase de envio e também não envia.

Comment: (continuando a mensagem anterior)
Ontem eu notei uma coisa estranha. Para o envio de dados do formulário, eu usei o POST. Só que no mobile, bizarramente, quando você clica em "Enviar", ele dá o refresh como eu disse, mas deixa na barra de endereço do navegador o conteúdo, como se fosse um GET, mas em nenhum lugar dos códigos tem o GET, ainda mais pra isso. Só uso o POST. 

Como você já está me ajudando, para tentar melhorar, eu subi o site no servidor, se quiser dar uma olhada ou fazer algum teste, fica à vontade, os emails caem no meu email particular!
www.sabconsel.com.br

Valeu! :)

Comment: Seu emal chegou aqui! =D

Comment: Porque me passou pela cabeça que poderia ser algum crash no mail, alguma incompatibilidade. Daí eu fiz um action mobile, só que os códigos são os mesmos, na verdade. Foi mais para testar, ver se poderia estar acontecendo algum tipo de incompatibilidade mesmo. Mas os dois são iguais. Eu tentei deixar o mail para os dois, mas também não deu certo. O que me intrigou ainda mais é esse formato "GET" na barra de endereço

Comment: Chegou outro email com os campos em branco [só para efeito de informação]

Comment: Beleza, vou fazer isso! E deixo no rodapé também ou só no head mesmo?

Comment: Coloquei tudo no <head> e, por via das dúvidas, deixei comentado tudo que estava no footer  ;)

Comment: Então, na teoria não era para influenciar, pois teoricamente, o formulário está repassando as mesmas informações para o mesmo lugar. Eu uso até os mesmos campos. Ele joga para o Slim Framework e esse faz todo o processo de envio usando o phpmailer. Mas sinceramente, não descarto essa possibilidade! Acho que vou fazer um teste então. Na versão mobile, queria deixar o site mais direto possível, mas vou recriar a página do "contato" e ver se funciona. Se funcionar, além da minha cabeça dar um parafuso final, ahaha, vou ficar muito feliz e vou colocar seu nome nos códigos como agradecimento! kkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está havendo conflito entre formulários na página. Quando você submete o segundo formulário, na verdade está enviando o primeiro. Para evitar isso, utilize o atributo HTML5 `formaction` em cada `button` *submit* de cada formulário.

**É necessário** incluir também o atributo `formmethod="post"`, e dispensar o atributo `method="post"` na *tag* `<form>`:

```
<form>
    <button formmethod="post" formaction="pagina1.php" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<form>
    <button formmethod="post" formaction="pagina2.php" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Compatibilidade:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Referências:**

- [formaction](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp)
- [formmethod](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formmethod.asp)

Comment: Cara, tá quase!!
Através do que você falou, eu refiz algumas coisas aqui e agora pelo menos ele manda o email, a única coisa é que manda com todos os campos vazios. Mas isso eu consigo ver depois!!
Só queria agradecer você por TODA essa atenção e por toda disposição em ajudar! MUITO OBRIGADO mesmo!!! Bom, independente se der certo ou nao, vejo aqui te falar para te dar uma consiferação! Abração cara!! Ótima quarta! =D

Comment: Cara, muito, muito, muito obrigado mesmo!!! Funcionou certinho aqui, finalmente!! Você me tirou um peso enorme das costas! É meu primeiro projeto comercial, então imagina a pressão, ahahah (Isso porque é um site simples!)
Como eu disse acima, obrigado por toda atenção que você deu! Espero um dia poder retribuir! E já está marcado ✔!! Valeu! =D